# Code actualising automatically variables when not desired

Tags: python, numpy

I have isolated the following part of a bigger code:

```
import numpy as np

population= np.random.normal(0,1,5)
individuals=population

print(population)

for i in range(len(individuals)):
    individuals[i]=0

print(population)
```

response:

```
[-0.1791731  -0.0756427   0.44463943 -0.51173395  0.9121922 ]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

I can't understand why the results are not identical.

Comment: I get an error: `name 'pop' is not defined`.  Do you mean `print(population)`?

Comment: what is the variable `pop`?

Comment: Also, the reason you get this output is because you point individuals as a reference to population, so you are changing population when you change individuals

Comment: Sorry changed the pop, that was a mistake

Comment: you change each item to `0` in the for loop... what is it you are trying to achieve with the for loop?

Comment: Actually the loop is bigger, but it's purpose is to changes the parameters among individuals, then I want to compare what changed compared to the initial ppopulation

Comment: What is the desired outcome? What is the loop supposed to do. Can you provide the actual code you have problems with and where it is going wrong..We need a little more to go on..

Comment: Thank you very much chrisz, that was the post I needed (about copying lists) ! So many hours lost...but now I understand a bit better python

Comment: Also I just created an account for this question and I am very impressed by your rapidity! Thank you again guys

Comment: `individuals` is just another name for `population` so changing one changes the other.

Comment: @martineau I'm not sure if the liked duplicate is correct for this question, it mentions `[:]` but that won't work on this np list. you need to use the objects `.copy()`. However, the generic `copy.copy(old_list)` should work too, but that's not really the *proper* way to copy an np list.

Comment: @ktzr: Perhaps the answer(s) aren't identical, but the problem this question asks about is, in my opinion...and it can be solved the same way—by making a copy of the list in whatever way is appropriate for its type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.copy()` if you want to copy the content of the numpy array, what you are doing at the moment, is copying a pointer to the list. 
So both variables point to the same data, so if one changes they both change.

```
import numpy as np

population= np.random.normal(0,1,5)
individuals=population.copy()

print(population)

for i in range(len(individuals)):
    individuals[i]=0

print(population)
```

For non-numpy lists you can use `[:]` eg

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a[:]
```

Comment: Oh I see, I just tested with [:] and as you told, it didn't work with numpy list. I am currently trying with .copy(), it works on the sample I gave here, but I am currently implementing it on my main code. I will come back to you if I have more problems. Thank you very much !

Comment: Use `population.copy()` not `[:]` as mentioned in the answer that is for non-numpy lists