# Clone a NumPy array multiple times

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, copy

I loaded a picture into a numpy array and need to threshold it picture at 2 different thresholds.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.Videocapture(0)
_,pic = cap.read()
pic1 = pic
pic2 = pic

pic1[pic1 > 100] = 255
pic2[pic2 > 200] = 255
```

This code will always edit pic when I only want them to modify pic1 and pic2

Comment: Similar issue 4 hrs ago.  [Code actualising automatically variables when not desired - duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321978/code-actualising-automatically-variables-when-not-desired).  When do different variables reference the same thing, as opposed to making a copy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python, there is a difference between an object and a variable. A variable is  name assigned to an object; and an object can have more than one name in memory.

By doing `pic1 = pic; pic2 = pic`, You're assigning the *same* object to multiple different variable names, so you end up modifying the same object.

What you want is to create copies using `np.ndarray.copy`—

```
pic1 = pic.copy()
pic2 = pic.copy()
```

Or, quite similarly, using `np.copy`—

```
pic1, pic2 = map(np.copy, (pic, pic))
```

This syntax actually makes it *really* easy to clone `pic` as many times as you like:

```
pic1, pic2, ... picN = map(np.copy, [pic] * N)
```

Where `N` is the number of copies you want to create.

Comment: @liliscent To me, it's neater than `pic1 = pic.copy(); pic2 = pic.copy()`, though I suppose it's a matter of taste.

Comment: I somehow find this kind of simplification will make code less readable. But anyway, it's just personal preference.

Comment: @liliscent Sure, I can respect that. I picked this up from Andras Deak, and found I quite liked the succinctness of it... of course it isn't for the faint of heart :p

Comment: Does the map function increase or decrease processing time? I hope to be processing a stream with the code. (I'm trying to determine the presence of 2 objects)

Comment: @Hojo.Timberwolf The difference is "seriously, don't worry about it" small, but you can look at the alt just below it if you're not interested.